# Solving system of linear inequalities in 3 or more variables - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to solve systems of linear inequalities in 3 or more variables. That is, to find *all* possible solutions.

I originally found GLPK and tried the python binding, but the last few updates to GLPK changed the APIs and broke the bindings. I haven't been able to find a way to making work.

I would like to have the symbolic answer, but numeric approximations will be fine too.

I would also be happy to use a library that solves maximization problem. I can always re-write the problems to be solve in that way.

Comment: Did you try SciPy? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html

Comment: @user189 I just checked it out. I may be wrong, but it doesn't seem to deal with inequalities.

Comment: SciPy does provide functions for minimizing and maximizing. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize

Answer (score -2):

make a matrix object and use Crammer's method